# What does the "_store" property means in a React object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was working on a React app that uses Redux, one component in particular is not rendering at all despite all the code around it *seemengly* working just fine, by logging the faulty components the only difference I managed to find between those who render and those who don't are the **_store** property of the react object

[image: object]

as you can see, _store is an object with only one property in it, **validated**, it is true on the components that do render and false on those who don't, I've been unable to find any information of what this means on the internet nor why it sometimes is true or false

My question is what is this property and what causes it to be false?

Comment: could you provide minimal reproducible code? people here not tend to click external links and read code from images. thank you!

Comment: sure, i can share the object json

Comment: `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {className: "picklist-disabled", children: "FPSS"}
ref: null
type: "span"
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 11, key: null, elementType: {…}, type: {…}, stateNode: null, …}
_store:
       validated: true
       __proto__: Object
_self: null
__proto__: Object`

Im ommiting the _source property jic of security

Answer (score 0):

When you create a react element, React assigns a `_store` property to the returned object **in dev mode** so that it can be used as a flag for validation.

You know that in React, every child in a list should have a unique key prop. [The validator](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactElementValidator.js#L122) checks this and shows an error in the console if we haven't provided the key. The validator changes the value of `element._store.validated` to `true` so that we won't run this validation again and again.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L168) you can find the code that adds the `_store` property to the element object. Note that the code is wrapped in `if (__DEV__)`. So `_store` won't be present in the production code.

`_store` (at least until now) has only one property: `validated` which is a `boolean`.
The reason that `validated` is not directly added to the element object is that the [react element is frozen](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L197) using `Object.freeze` but the validator function needs to mutate it and change it to `true` to flag the element as "validated".

That said, this property is only a flag for a warning-level error and it won't determine whether your component should render or not.